# Error (Failed to convert parameter value from a String to a DateTime)

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I want to save Date and Time in Access DB field which its DataType is Date/Time. So this Error ( Failed to convert parameter value from a String to a DateTime )

```
Cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@DateAdded", OleDbType.Date)).Value =
    Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss")
Cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@DateModified", OleDbType.Date)).Value =
    Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why try to convert to string? Just use the DateTime value directly.

```
Cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@DateAdded", OleDbType.Date)).Value = Now
Cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@DateModified", OleDbType.Date)).Value = Now
```

Your code most likely fails because the format you specify (`"dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"`) is not the format of the culture your application runs with, so the systems fails converting the generated string to a DateTime because it does not recognize the format used.